# How to remove the time out of this date?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, count

I'm trying to remove the time out of this date while still keeping it as a date (not a character) because that can't be sorted correctly.

Currently a data looks like this : 02-NOV-2020 00:00 
I want it like this: 02-NOV-2020

My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT,
    TRUNC(CREATED_AT) DATES
FROM FRESHDESK_API
WHERE TRUNC(CREATED_AT) > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 32
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATED_AT)
ORDER BY TRUNC(CREATED_AT) ASC
```

Comment: Dates in Oracle have the time. If you want to format a date, you need to change it into a string, with `to_char`

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase the query like so:

```
select count(*) as amount, to_char(created_at, 'DD-MON-YYYY') dates
from freshdesk_api
where created_at >= trunc(sysdate) - 31
group by to_char(created_at, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
order by min(created_at)
```

Rationale:

- `to_char()` formats the date to the target string display format - there is no need to `trunc()` inside `to_char()`
- the `group by` clause neeeds to be consistent with the `select`
- `TRUNC(CREATED_AT) > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 32` can be optimized as `created_at >= trunc(sysdate) - 31`; no date functions are applied to `created_at`, so this is more efficient (the query may take advantage of an index on the date column). Note that if you want one month, you should use `add_months(trunc(sysdate), -1)` instead (not all months have 31 days)
- If you want a date-wise sort in the `order by` clause, you can use an aggregate function

Comment: `order by dates` will sort the data as a string and not a date.

Comment: @Popeye (aka Tejash... right?): yes that's a good point, thank you. I edited my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TO_CHAR` to display it while using other code as it is. (Sorting will be via `TRUNC(CREATED_AT)`) as follows:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CREATED_AT),'DD-MON-YYYY') DATES -- Display it using TO_CHAR 
FROM FRESHDESK_API
WHERE TRUNC(CREATED_AT) > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 32
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATED_AT) 
ORDER BY TRUNC(CREATED_AT) ASC -- sort it using date
```

Answer (score 1):

How dates are shown in application dependent.  However, in most cases, the time component is (sadly) lost.

If `created_at` is a `timestamp` rather than a `date`, then converting it to a date should do what you want:

```
 select cast(timestamp as date)
```

Note that the time component is still part of the value, but just not shown.  So, you can use `trunc()`:

```
 select trunc(cast(timestamp as date))
```

If you are still getting the time component, then you need to either reconfigure the tool you are using or settle for a string.  Your question specifically says you don't want a string, but that is really the only way to have full control over the format.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb43eb1899a092514eefffee69460009) is a little db<>fiddle.